# Decoding bytes to utf-8 returns different results

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, python-3.5

I have installed Python 3.5.2 on my local machine and I've installed Python 3.5.2 in Docker container with `virtualenv -p python3.5 env`.

I ran the same command in both interpreters and I've get different results:

On local machine this code:

```
b'\xc5\xbc'.decode('utf-8')
```

returns `'ż'`, which is expected beaviour.

In Docker container the same code returns me `'\u017c'`.

Why? How to fix that?

Comment: `\u017c` **is the same character as 'ż'**.

Comment: Are you sure you are running Python 3 in Docker? Python 2 uses `\uhhhh` escapes when you echo a Unicode value with codepoints outside of the Latin-1 range.

Comment: Yes, but why I get something different printed to my console?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, yes: ```env/bin/python3.5          
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> b'\xc5\xbc'.decode('utf-8')
'\u017c'
```

Comment: Ah, that's probably your console encoding.

Comment: Compare `import sys; print(sys.stdout.encoding)`.

Comment: Oh, there is ANSI_X3.4-1968 encoding in Docker's console. How can I change it?

Comment: That's ASCII. What does `locale` in the shell (not in Python) produce? This is a shell configuration issue, not a Python issue.

Comment: ```LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=```

Comment: Ok, I've added `ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8` to Dockerfile and that helped. 

Thanks for help @MartijnPieters!